# How will app behave if it has a feature which uses BLE and the device does not have needed hardware?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building a feature which uses Bluetooth low energy. I was wondering what will happen if same application is ran on the device without BLE support?

Comment: on iOS you will never get a bluetooth "powered on" status, so your app will be unable to scan or connect to any devices.  How you handle it from this point is up to your app

Comment: I just need to broadcast some data. I don't want to connect to or scan any device. Will it still be able to broadcast the UUID and device name?

Comment: If the device doesn't have BLE hardware then you can't send or receive. For is this means you need an iPhone4s or later or an iPad mini or later http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/973945